# SQL GROUP BY with MAX as Linq?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core

this simple question is turning my head upside down. I want to get, without client side evaluation, the latest date of an order of each user. I know how to get this information in plain SQL, does someone know how to convert this into Linq to SQL on entity framework core?

here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
  orders.*
FROM
  (SELECT
     user_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM
     orders
   GROUP BY
     user_id) AS latest_orders
INNER JOIN
  orders
ON
  orders.user_id = latest_orders.user_id AND
  orders.created_at = latest_orders.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

First `GroupBy` UserId, then select all the List in a groupby by userId then `OrderByDescending` by date then take top one

```
var ListOrder=orders.GroupBy(x=>x.user_id ).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.created_at).Take(1));
```

Comment: HI Ashim, thank you for your answer, but GroupBy would be evaluated on the client side. This means that even before I could OrderBy and Take 1, the SQL server would have returned me all of my orders from the entire table, for a big table with many users and many orders, that would mean returning tens of thousands of records instead of hundreds.